# XML DOM, PHP sending 1's to XML?

Tags: javascript, php, xml

Cant figure this one out. My PHP seems fine, the commented out code when left in was producing 2 XML sets of data. The output to XML is '1' under each element.... Why?

```
PHP:
<?php 
echo "Submission Successful!";
echo "<a href='buyonline.htm'>Back</a>";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("data/customer.xml");
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;

$custid = uniqid();
$firstname = isset($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = isset($_POST['lastname']);
$email = isset($_POST['email']);
$password = isset($_POST['password']);
$phone = isset($_POST['phone']);

/*$firstname = htmlentities($firstname, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$lastname = htmlentities($lastname, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$email = htmlentities($email, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$password = htmlentities($password, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
$phone = htmlentities($phone, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);*/

$customers = $dom->getElementsByTagName("customers")->item(0);

    $customertag = $dom->createElement("customer");

        $custidtag = $dom->createElement("custid", $custid);
        $firstnametag = $dom->createElement("firstname", $firstname);
        $lastnametag = $dom->createElement("lastname", $lastname);
        $emailtag = $dom->createElement("email", $email);
        $passwordtag = $dom->createElement("password", $password);
        $phonetag = $dom->createElement("phone", $phone);

    $customertag->appendChild($custidtag);
    $customertag->appendChild($firstnametag);
    $customertag->appendChild($lastnametag);
    $customertag->appendChild($emailtag);
    $customertag->appendChild($passwordtag);
    $customertag->appendChild($phonetag);


$customers->appendChild($customertag);

$dom->save('data/customer.xml');


?>

XML: 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<customers>
<customer>
    <custid>
    </custid>
    <firstname>
    </firstname>
    <lastname>
    </lastname>
    <email>
    </email>
    <password>
    </password>
    <phone>
    </phone>
</customer>
<customer><custid>562b5d237b599</custid><firstname>1</firstname>    
<lastname>1</lastname><email>1</email><password>1</password><phone>1
</phone></customer></customers>
```

I can post HTML and JS if you guys need. Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `isset` returns **true** or **false**, depending whether variable set or not.

Doing `$phone = isset($_POST['phone'])` means that `$phone` get value `true` or `false`. Writing boolean `true` value to a file ends in converting it to `1`.

I suppose you want to check if value set and set some default value if it's not. You can do it this way:

```
$phone = isset($_POST['phone'])? $_POST['phone'] : 'DEFAULT';
```

You can put any value instead of `'DEFAULT'`.

**Update**:
about commented code. Not sure you should use it or not. But the case of this code is the next: suppose someone enter his lastname as `I am <robot/>`. When you put it directly to you xml-file you will receive something like:

```
<lastname>I am <robot/></lastname>
```

See, you get another xml-tag `robot` which is inside `lastname`. Unexpected! That's why you should escape you values.
But I'm not sure - should you do it implicitly or maybe `DOM` library do it too while exporting to an xml-file. So you can try and check it out by yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Works perfectly! Do you know whether i need to use the code that is commented out, it was recommended but i dont know why?